# Type of DC motors for generators

Tags: motor, generator

I'm looking for a motor to produce 11V. I'm a little confused about which type of motor should I use. The shaft of the motor is connected to the nitro engine and it will rotate the shaft of the motor.

I'm actually designing a generator. I'm not sure what type of motor should I use.  Brushless? Brushed? Permanent magnet?

I just need to produce only 11V to produce electricity.

I'm actually designing a generator to charge a LiPo battery. I'm using a 3 cell LiPo battery. The 3 cell LiPo battery is equaled to 11V. So I have to work the reverse engineering way.

How can I produce 11 V from the most suitable motor and nitro engine?

That's what I'm figuring it out. Like what are the best motor and engine to produce 11V.

Comment: 11 V at which load (current)? (if you don't know, it would be good to tell us what you want to power with this.) That defines whether you need a nuclear plant turbine generator, or something the size of a wristband watch motor. Before you ask: no general recommendation can be given.

Comment: You have to specify the rated speed and torque (or power at the rated speed) of the nitro engine.

Comment: And why 11 V? That is not a standard voltage for anything I know about. 12 V would be much more common.

Comment: I'm actually designing a generator to charge the LiPo battery. I'm using a 3 cells LiPo battery. 3 cells LiPo battery is equaled to 11V. So I have to work the reverse engineering way. How can I produce 11 V from the most suitable motor and nitro engine, That's what I'm figuring it out. Like what are the best motor and engine to produce 11V.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a DC motor to a generator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/215997/converting-a-dc-motor-to-a-generator) and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/290871/dc-brushless-motor-specs-for-generator

Comment: Here is another question that is similar: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/423029/best-most-efficient-motor-type-to-be-used-as-a-dc-generator

Comment: And that's not how charging Lithium batteries works, by the way. You will need a charge controller, unless you like exploding or otherwise damaged Lithium batteries. You design this from the wrong end. Start with clearly defining how fast you need to charge batteries of which capacities with what mechanical source. That will set mechanical requirements for your motor. The voltage coming out of that motor is of little role, actually, since your charge controller will convert that, anyway. So, you picked one of the least relevant technical aspects to start your motor choice.

Comment: You MUST say what the battery's mAh capacity is and what sort of charge rate you require. | To fully charge a LiIon battery it needs 4.2V/cell - and you need to either control charging correctly by design or use a charger IC that has this ability. | 11V/3 =~ 3.7V is the AVERAGE voltage of a LiIon cell - NOT the target charge voltage. Charging a 3S pack at 11V will only result in about 50% capacity or less.